# Select the best selling product ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

What if I have table like this and I want to select the best selling product_id.

| id | transaction_id | product_id | qty_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 22 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 23 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 24 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 25 | 2 | 4 |

I want the best selling `product_id` with the highest `qty_sold`

Comment: look up `group by` and `sum()` in your database docs.

Comment: Best selling as in "product ID with the highest sum of qty_sold" or "highest count of transactions" ? If a product sells 1000 in 1 transaction, or 1 qty in 500 transactions, which is the best seller?

Comment: You will need double-aggregation - first `SUM()` then `MAX()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 or perhaps a TOP 1

Comment: @CaiusJard Best selling product_id with the highest sum of qty_sold

Comment: And what about ties? If product 1 has 1 transaction with 1000 qty, and product 2 has 500 transactions with 2 qty, which is the best seller? Or is it both? And what database do you use (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, SQLServer etc)?

Comment: @Caius Jard I want the `product_id` that comes first in the table, Im using SQLServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLS, you can group by the productID, add up the number of sold, and order by the total descending. If we also take the minimum transaction ID per product, if two products come out to have the same total qty, we can take the minimum tran ID to split the tie

```
SELECT TOP 1 product_id, SUM(qty_sold) as sellcount, MIN(transaction_id) as firsttran
FROM t
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM(qty_sold) DESC, MIN(transaction_id)
```

Once you're happy the sums are right etc, you can remove the `, SUM(qty_sold) as sellcount, MIN(transaction_id)` from the SELECT if you want/if you only need the prod ID